# Travelling with an emergency passport

Tags: transit, passports, switzerland, south-african-citizens

Can I transit in Zurich, Switzerland, on my way back to South Africa with an emergency passport issued by the South African consulate in Paris? Do I need a transit visa for this flight with the emergency passport?

Comment: Where will you be transiting?

Comment: Through  Zurich Switzerland.

Comment: Would you need a visa for a regular passport?

Comment: @Max: One possible complication _might_ be that he presumably had a Schengen visa in the passport he lost and now doesn't have any. But I can't imagine that actually causing any trouble with the Swiss; that would be a very usual case when passports are lost.

Comment: What did the SA consulate advise when they issued the emergency passport?

Comment: You're already in the Schengen area. This is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's what an emergency passport is - a passport.  It's meant to be traveled with.

As to transiting through an airport, that usually doesn't require a passport, since you're not technically entering the country.  But in this case especially if you're coming from Paris and so already in the Schengen area.

Comment: "transiting through an airport usually doesn't require a passport, since you're not technically entering the country": this depends entirely on the country in question.  For example, a French citizen traveling to French Caribbean territories in transit through the US does require a passport (and either ESTA or a visa), even though one would not be required for a direct flight.